# ObjectDisposedException thrown in a xamlx on hitting a Receive/Send activity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, workflow-foundation

Seems that WF runtime is trying to persist its variables when hitting one Receive and Send couple activities.

One of the variable is an entity object. When accessing it, got an

**ObjectDisposedException**

thrown from the entity designer file, (on a foreign key field).

> The object instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for
>   operations that require a connection.

Edit : Does it have something to do with the **lazy loading** funcitonnality in entity framework ?
I'm stating that because, exception occurs on a member of my entity which is a foreign key (a relation with other enity).

Comment: Crazy, I set **Enable Lazy Loading** to False on my EDM properties and solved the problem.
Well now I'm having another issue with all my linq query on the model. They don't return anything unless I separate access to parent and linked entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lazily loading the object, try releasing it from the context before using it. (or make sure it's wrapped in the `using` statement.)

To release, just call `detach()` on the context.

Comment: Every manipulation of my entities are inbetween a _using_ statement brackets. I use entity objects without any problems in the activities of the workflow. Though, this exception is thrown when the receive response activity is being executed.

Comment: Are you loading all of the entities which are related? Using `.Include` in your select statement?

Comment: You're right doctor. It doesn't work if `Include` method is not used in my linq expressions. So I'm using it.

Is this a good practice ? I'm a little confused about using _magic string_ for setting child entities names for them to be linked and actually loaded.

Comment: I believe using the `Include` is quite normal. There's more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx